# Change display style in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I want to change the style of each element inside enumerate.
It should be:

```
Ad (1)
Ad (2)
```

I have tried to do it by:

```
\begin{enumerate}[Ad. (1)]
  \item 
  \item
\end{enumerate}
```

But a result is not what I expected. I would like to change it only locally inside specific enumerate block. And I don't want to use any extra package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the definition of the label for the first level enumerate environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{Ad (\theenumi)}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note that the effect is temporary; it only applies to this instance of enumerate. Also, if you embed enumerates within each other then inner instances will use `enumii`, `enumiii` and `enumiv` in place of `enumi`.